# Decrypt HTTPS connections Android Mobile App

Tags: android, ssl, https, fiddler, mitmproxy

We have an important research project regarding mobile dating apps. One of the research points is also data being transferred to 3rd parties.

So, we had to decrypt HTTPS connections by doing a man-in-the-middle approach.

We used Fiddler as well as Mitmproxy. We also used Android emulator Bluestacks (rooted) as well as regular cell phones (Android < 6 (5.1) and Android v8 and v9). Installing root certificates worked fine.

However, we encountered a problem with one app "Grindr" (the world’s leading gay dating app).

We received "Grindr insecure connection" when starting the app. Deactivating the proxy, starting/using the app and then re-activated the proxy again,
we could capture HTTPS for just a short amount of time until this message has been displayed again. We assume that's an inner app code issue?

We downloaded different versions of app via apkmirror.com and used APK Tool to decompile the re-build the app and signed the app afterwards (e.g. APK signer, play store) and included some changes due to:

*Four Ways to Bypass Android SSL Verification and Certificate Pinning

https://blog.netspi.com/four-ways-bypass-android-ssl-verification-certificate-pinning/*

A wired thing: The original downloaded/mirrored APK could not be installed most of the time and if, after Grindr restarts, the app stopped. We tried different versions. (the lower versions worked better)

When there is no internet connection, the app opens properly and points to the login screen. I guess there must be a background check or URL callback (config.safedk.com?). However bypassing specific IP addresses didn't help.

Does anybody have experiences with this issue or any solution to overcome the "Grindr insecure connection" pop up?

Comment: Did the Frida unpinning way work with Grinder? IMHO this is the way with the highest chance of success in case the app uses SSL pinning. Although I prefer Magisk + Xposed + JustTrustMe and SSLUnpinning modules.

Comment: Hi Robert, it did not work. We tried couple of Android versions though. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: If it does not work the app is additionally protected. If you want to make it work you have to analyze what the app does. Therefore decompile it using apktool, Jadx, Jeb, ... and analyze the code. Note that this can get very hard and require a lot of time and skill.